# Java Program failing to connect to MQ "unable to connect to queue manager, check remote access to MQ installation"

Tags: java, linux, ibm-mq

To clarify the issue.  I am running an MQ simulator jar given to us by a vendor (essentially to verify or MQ setup prior to them delivering MQ functionality).

1. The program works, when I run it from my laptop.
2. I get "unable to connect to queue manager, check remote access to MQ installation" when I run it from the linux dev server (which is where we actually want to verify the connectivity from).  Same exact MQ properties as when I run from my windows laptop.  I ran telnet from the server to the host and port and confirmed that worked.  So I imagine there shouldn't be any firewall rule preventing the connection.

The program doesn't actually print out an error code, just the message (which I am pretty sure is the first question that is going to get asked of me).

I've been talking to the folks that set up MQ, and they are really making it sound like it isn't an issue on their end despite the fact most everything I can find on this message is indicating it is probably a problem with configuration there.

Not super linux savvy so any tips on any way I can monitor and get more information on a root cause other than this error message I am seeing would be great.

Comment: Yeah, you really need the MQ Reason Code that was returned from the MQ API call.  My first guess is that it is a security issue.  Are you running the program under the same UserId?  Also, are you using the same MQ JAR files on the Linux server as on your Windows PC?  Did the MQAdmin setup CHLAUTH rules that blocks connections from particular IP addresses or only allows connections from a particular IP addresses,

Comment: Have the MQAdmin turn on the queue manager Authority Events, do the test again then have the MQAdmin review the authority events that were generated.

Comment: Start the test program with the following Java system property to enable a JMS trace that you can review to see some more detail `java -Dcom.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.trace.status=ON application_name`